# Storing a timestamp as a default value in hstore

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I am trying to store the current timestamp as a default value in an hstore. I tried using `now()` but all that is stored is `"last_collected"=>"now()"`. Here is what I have:

```
'"level"=>"1", "last_collected"=>now()'::hstore
```

Is there a correct way to do this or is it even possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using one of the [`hstore` constructor functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE) would probably be easier:

> `hstore(text[])`: construct an hstore from an array, which may be either a key/value array, or a two-dimensional array.
>   `hstore(text[], text[])`: construct an hstore from separate key and value arrays.

So you could use one of these:

```
hstore(array['level', '1', 'last_collected', now()::text])
hstore(array[array['level', '1'], array['last_collected', now()::text]])
hstore(array['level', 'last_collected'], array['1', now()::text])
```

Keep in mind that hstore uses `text` for both the keys and values so your timestamp will be a string. You might want to use [`to_char`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) instead of `::text` to convert your timestamp to a string, that will give you more control over the precision and format.

```
hstore(ARRAY['level', '1', 'last_collected', to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'HH12:MI:SS')]);
```